# how D0 I make the flistList clickable and how Do I know exactly which Item had clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

> how D0 I make the flistList clickable and how Do I know exactly which
> Item had clicked, for Example when the user clicks the first element I
> want to show him array of images and if he clicks element number 2 I
> will show him another array of element

```
        <View onPress={()=>alert("")}>
            <FlatList 
                vertical={true}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={imgs}
                keyExtractor={(images) => images.name}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <Image source={item.img}
                        key={index}
                        style={{
                            width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
                            height: 300,
                            borderWidth: 5,
                            borderColor: "red",
                            margin: 4
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>
    </Block>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new react component which will have the structure in which you want to render each item in your flatlist and inside that component, inside its `render()` instance, wrap everything inside `TouchableOpacity` which has an `onPress` prop where you can set what you want when a user clicks an item. Then, inside your main component, inside the `renderItem` prop of `FlatList`, map each item which you want to render with the new react component created.

Answer (score 1):

```
<FlatList 
      vertical={true}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={imgs}
      keyExtractor={(images) => images.name}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
     <Pressable onPress={()=> alert('Item you clicked', item)}>
        <Image source={item.img}
               key={index}
               style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
                       height: 300,
                       borderWidth: 5,
                       borderColor: "red",
                       margin: 4
                        }}
                    />
      </Pressable>
       )}
   />
```

Use this snippet. Analyze it.